# Grant Admin Consent to Azure Application for GraphAPI Permissions Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created an AzureAD Application, assigned the GraphAPI permissions it needs, and created the ServicePrincipal. So far everything is good to go, except that I can not find out how to grant the admin consent for those needed GraphAPI permissions. I' trying to grant admin permissions via powershell without(!) login prompt for the admin.

[image]

I found

```
    GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
&scope=
https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read
https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send
```

and modified it for my needs. All I get in the response is html code. (There is nowhere documented if, and what header is to be included in the request which makes it more confusing)

I do not have the opportunity to create an admin App/ServicePrincipal do use to grant the admin consent.

This will all run in Azure Runbooks, so waiting for a pop-up prompt is not an option.

Comment: Will "Grant admin consent for <Tenant Name>" option in the API permissions permission of the page help ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#grant-admin-consent-from-the-azure-portal

Comment: Does  Grant admin consent button is grayed out to your application can you please make sure that you are an admin to that particular tenant?

Comment: Im trying to admin consent via powershell. The solution you posted opens a login prompt for the admin. This is not an option because im trying to get this to run in Azure Runbook

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog: [**Provide Admin Consent for Azure AD Applications Programmatically**](https://samcogan.com/provide-admin-consent-fora-azure-ad-applications-programmatically/)

You can achieve this using below command:

```
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/oauth2PermissionGrants"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)" }  -Method POST -Body $($body | convertto-json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Azure CLI is not supporten in runbooks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant the admin consent for all the Application permissions and Delegated permissions at one time, there is no such powershell command to do that without an admin user-interactive way.

Your option is to use the service principal related to the automation RunAs Account to get the token, then use the token to call the Microsoft Graph [`Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [`Create a delegated permission grant(oAuth2PermissionGrant)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in the runbook, don't forget to give the required permission for your RunAs Account service principal.

To get the token, you could use the command below. After getting the token, use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7) to call the API.

```
$context = Get-AzContext
$accesstoken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically:

az ad app permission admin-consent --id $appId

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to grant the admin consent through the UI there should be a button right beside the one where you add the permissions:

[image]